# Clicking/Tapping Screen Coordinates on Netflix/Prime/Hulu App on AndroidTV device

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-tv, netflix

I am trying to automate a user experience on AndroidTV Apps which don't have a standard android view hierarchy (probably written using openGL framework).
I can provide the dump of the view of any of these apps if needed.

I'm trying to fire a click event for a particular button, say 'ABC' which is present at the 'x y' coordinates on the screen.

For native android ATV apps, I can do that by firing an 'adb tap x y' event or `UiDevice.click(x,y)`.

However, I'm not able to do so with Netflix, Prime, Youtube or Hulu Apps for ATV.
The click/tap is actually triggered on the screen, but the button doesn't respond to that.
Maybe because it's part of just a View(Framelayout) and not actually a button in the openGL world.

I don't want to use the D-Pad Remote Control events for this.
(Maybe, shift focus to that coordinate and then press dpad centre can. work)

Is there any way I can achieve that ?

Comment: How about something like AutoMouseClicker?

Comment: Can it be used programmatically from code ?